# Scala/SBT dependent compilation

Tags: scala, sbt

I want somehow inject environment specific information at build time of my project.

For instance I have some integration tests stage where several subsystems are mocked out. I want to define such stage-dependent information at compile time (no configuration + reflection or JVM-parameter).

My idea:

- stage-dependent information will be injected as implicit `Environment` variable.
- every stage dependent class will have a import of `Environment` and have a implicit environment parameter.
- in my sbt file I will trigger compile time code generation of this `Environment`-class (for instance I can generate some dummies for our test-stage).

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Can you use system properties for this?

Comment: @Mr.V. sure I can use some kind of environment variable. But I want somehow build stage dependent artifacts without external dependencies (like env vars, jvm flags etc.)